# Is there a way I can plot different elements of an array using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have the following array:

```
popul_num = np.array([200, 100, 0, 0])
```

Each element of the array represents the number of Enzyme, substrate, Enzyme-substrate complex and product in the system.

I have written code to simulate the following reactions over time and update popul_num to change the values of each entity as it is either consumed or produced:

E + S --> ES

ES --> E + S

ES --> E + P

The functions then update the popul_num array with new values according to the above reactions having happened.

I'm trying to use Matplotlib to plot a line graph of the changes in entity numbers over time as a result of the above reactions occurring

I've tried calling plt.plot once for each index of the array:

```
plt.plot(popul_num[i]) # i in place of each index
```

and I've tried:

```
plt.plot(popul_num[0:3])
```

but both methods always just return a one line plot, what am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: The question is vauge. plt.plot(popul_num), plots the points (0,200), (1,100), (2,0), and (3,0). Are those the points you want to plot? How many points are you trying to plot? What did you change about the points that you want to plot?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting to see? What kind of graph you desire? What population_num new values are? Can you give an example of what popul_num looks before plotting? Also, please attach the graphs you get and explain what you are expecting to see. You can always use scatter plot (https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the new state rather than updating it.

```
popul_num = np.array([200, 100, 0, 0])

#after single reaction

popul_num = np.array([200, 100, 0, 0], [300, 50, 2, 4])

# now plot 4 separate graphs

for i in range(4):
 plt.plot(list(enumerate(popul_num[:, i])))

plt.show()
```